# How to load json files into a barchart?

Tags: python, json, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to load json files in a barchart. The code for the barchart is the following.

```
#visualization 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
    
df = df[:20,]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.barplot(df.values, df.index, 0.8)
plt.title ('Top Words Overall')
plt.ylabel('Words from Tweet', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Count of Words', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

I am very glad for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Read your JSON to a dataframe first, which you can use to build the chart. How you read JSON data to a df would depend on your data structure.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

example_json = '{ "values": [ {"value": 10, "parameter": "A"},{"value": 33, "parameter": "B"}, {"value": 5, "parameter": "C"}]}'

data = json.loads(example_json)

'''
Use this if json data is in a separate file
1. Open the file
file = open(<path_to_your_file>)
2. Read json data
data = json.load(file)
'''

df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['values'])
```

This is one way of reading JSON data to a df, which we could then use to build a simple bar chart.